# Delete pattern "A B 'c'" from lines that don't contain Z

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

File1:

```
Z "A B 'c'" A
D "A B 'c'" B
GH H
```

Desired output:

```
Z "A B 'c'" A
D B
GH H
```

How can I remove the pattern `" A B 'c' "`, but only in lines which do not contain pattern `Z`, using `bash`, `awk`, `sed`, or `grep`?

Comment: Tagging the question solely with [shell] is not helpful. Consider that `sh`, `bash`, `ksh`, etc. are all shells. *For questions about shell scripting, please use a more specific tag such as `bash`, `powershell` or `ksh`. Without a specific tag, a portable (POSIX-compliant) solution should be assumed, though using `posix` in addition or `sh` instead is preferable.* — from the [shell] tag description.

Comment: is that Possible To Remove the pattern " A B 'c' "  From the file with Grep , AWK or Sed Command . If yes , then let Me Know..How

Comment: Do `cat` and paste the exact output here please.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed`, but before that get around `bash`'s quoting restrictions so that `sed` has the correct target string.  First *single quote* the pattern's double quotes as far as possible, and then *double quote* the single quotes, and repeat as needed:

```
sed '/Z/!s/"A B '"'c'"'" //g' File1
```

Comment: Perfect ! and so a ^

Comment: `grep` can only print matches; it cannot replace substrings. Additionally, `grep` accepts a list of regexes, but it gets clumsy if the order of the substrings is arbitrary. `sed` and Awk are simply a much better choice for this task.

Comment: Can use ansi c string to make it look nicer `sed $'/Z/!s/"A B \'c\'"//'`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use single quotes inside a single quote delimited script. That's a shell thing, and applies whether it's an awk or sed or any other script. There's various workarounds but the simplest and most robust is to use the octal number that represents a `'`, i.e. `\047`, instead:

```
$ awk '!/Z/{sub(/"A B \047c\047"/,"")} 1' file
Z "A B 'c'" A
D  B
GH H
```

Note that when you remove the string you're interested in it leaves 2 blanks between D and B. Add a blank to whichever end of the RE is correct to resolve that if you care.

Comment: Line #2 of the output should be: `D B`.

Comment: its a Wrong Output , Can U improvise It...@Ed Morton..I need The Answer Pls

Answer (score 0):

Was about [[ answer ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38259572/1620779) the same way [[ @ed-morton ]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) did but now I feel tempted to post a variant of the answer which uses hexadecimal representation of `'` ie `\x27`

```
awk '!/Z/{sub(/"A B \x27\c\x27"/,"")}1' 38258963
```

**Output**

```
Z "A B 'c'" A
D  B
GH H
```

---

**Note**

The only difference here is that you need to escape the `c` which also is a hexadecimal digit coz it is close knit to `single quote` in the pattern

Comment: @sjsam Never use the hex representation, always use octal. See http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote

Comment: @Shetty no, this is just not a job for grep. grep is to search for a regexp and print a matching string, it is not for editing text, e.g. by removing parts of lines.

Comment: @ Ed Morton , That Your Awk Command Is Removing Only first pattern found In the line , But I have Many Similar Pattern "A B 'c'" in the Line and I want to Remove All those .....Please Help.